# vscode debugger shows imported variables with an _ "underscore" prefix when using babel-node or node -r @babel/register

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, babeljs

While debugging my ES6 babel-node project in vscode I see imported modules/objects include an _ "underscore" as a prefix. So as an example;

### './Foo.js'

```js
export default class Foo{ constructor() {} }
```

#### './index.js'

```js
import Foo from './Foo';
```

in the debugger shows up as `_Foo` instead of `Foo`
[image]

if it matters my `.babelrc` is

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": "both",
}
```